# Disable access to addon domain through maindomain.com/addondomainfolder

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory, addon-domain

I want to disable access to the folder of my addon domain using .htaccess but I can't seem to figure it out.

My folder structure is like this:

```
root/maindomain (www.maindomain.com/maindomain)
root/addondomain (www.addondomain.com)
```

I want to disable access to my addon domain through the *www.maindomain.com/addondomain* url.

How would I do this?

My htaccess file in the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?swen\.me.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?creepypastaindex http://www.creepypastaindex.com/ [L,R]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?swen.me.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/swen/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /swen/$1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do. You have to escape both dots.

```
RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?swen\.me\.uk$ [NC]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/creepypastaindex/(.*)$
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
```

[Source](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/498)

Comment: Perfect answer providing source for further learning helps us noobs - thanks Aamir.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in the document root of your main domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?addondomain - [L,F]
```

If you want to redirect it somewhere instead of returning a 403 forbidden, change the last line to something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/?addondomain http://www.maindomain.com/ [L,R]
```

Comment: I tried adding this to the htaccess file in my root folder but it didn't seem to work for me. I updated my question to include the htaccess file I'm using.